# Почему "приискренний" с приставкой "при", а не "пре"?

Tags: орфография, грамматика, морфемика, приставка

Это какое-то исключение или такое написание связано с происхождением слова?

Comment: На чем основана уверенность, что правильно "при-"?

Comment: Можете привести цитату, откуда взято это слово?

Comment: Как отметили @РиммаМихайлова и Aer,  «приискренний» это церковнославянизм.

Answer (score 2):

**Преискренний ― очень искренний**, приставка ПРЕ имеет значение превосходной степени, сравнить забавный ― презабавный.

**Для сравнения**: общим значением приставки ПРИ является приближение, например: чудо ― причудливый, то есть подобный чуду (приближенный к чуду).

Редкое слово, вот единственный пример из Нацкорпуса:

«Для изъяснения и усвоения великого догмата о воплощении Христовом святитель Кирилл ищет разнообразных и разносторонних выражений ― и в пятницу после утрени молится так: "Иисусе, спасенное имя...", ― такой **преискренний** оборот находит святитель».

Слова с приставкой ПРЕ не всегда можно найти в словаре, в этом случае их относят **к авторским неологизмам.**

Answer (score 1):

В словарях прилагательное ***пре***искренний и наречие ***пре***искренне действительно отсутствуют, "редактор" слова отмечает как ошибку. Но я бы не стала их относить к неологизмам: нечасто, конечно, но слова используются:

*Если почва уходит

У нас под  ног,

Может стоит

Над миром взлететь?

Это сколько же может

**Преискренний**  Бог,

За ленивыми

Нами смотреть!*
В. Назарова. Взлетай

*Любви, **преискренний** служитель,

Ей посвятил весь путь земной,

Её премудрости благой,

Был ученик и тайнозритель.*
А. Ерёмин. Иоанн Богослов, апостол и евангелист

*Радуйся, верных и неверных посещающая; радуйся, **преискренне** спасения всем хотящая* (из молитвы).

*Под его взглядом мне всегда было как-то неуютно; **искренний-преискренний**, душа нараспашку, васильковый взгляд, ставший модным в первую волну звезд голливудского «техниколора».*
[**Э. Мартин. Деньги**](http://book-online.com.ua/read.php?book=4989&page=10)

*Это таинство, в котором мы **преискренне** соединяемся с богом, превосходит другие...*
[(212) **Толстой Л. Н. против "семи таинств**"](http://az.lib.ru/t/tolstoj_lew_nikolaewich/text_1120.shtml)

["Приискренний", думаю, вот отсюда:
Радуйся, всеблагих советов Пресвятыя Троицы приискренний таинниче. Радуйся...
Радуйся, приискренний Иисусов любителю. Радуйся, сыне благословенный Отца Небеснаго.

[**Полный церковно-славянский словарь** (с внесением в него важнейших древнерусских слов и выражений)](http://www.orthodic.org/?searchCs=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8%D1%81&searchRu=&type=cs&go.x=0&go.y=0)]

**Дополнение**

Слово "приискренний" используется, но только в церковно-славянском языке (см. ссылку).
В **современном** русском языке грамотно употреблять ***преискренний, преискренне*** — это никоим образом не противоречит общим правилам словообразования.

Comment: Думаю, что стоит более явно обозначить, что «приискренний» это церковнославянизм, значащий «такой же, равнообразный».

Comment: Благодарю за наставление. Внесла дополнение в ответ.